# Align text center of footer

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

this is my first post.
I need to someone that help me with this problem with footer on my website.
I create this with Bootstrap 3.3.7 and my footer is this:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-title">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
          <p>LEFT</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="navbar-text">
          <p>PROVA MESSAGGIO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
          <p>RIGHT</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to position the `PROVA MESSAGGIO` paragraph in the middle of the footer using class `navbar-text`. How can this be done?

Comment: Please edit it as code snippet, not as code sample. Thanks.

Comment: You have the **Bootstrap 4** tag (wrong version). Please retag for BS 3.

Comment: Sorry i choose wrong tag

Comment: can you add inside some other class, or you can't modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/886/

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-title">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
          <p>LEFT</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="navbar-text no-float"><!--This was floating. Hence it was not aligned-->
          <p class="text-center">PROVA MESSAGGIO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
          <p>RIGHT</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.no-float {
  float: none;
}
```

**Explanation:** navbar-text has `float:left;` which moves the element out of the flow. For, central aligning, you need the elements to be in flow so as to take their parent's width. Removing the float and then using text-center does the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify your HTML code then you can go with the following solution. Apply `width:100%` and `text-align:center` for the `navbar-text`. Make sure you are targeting only the second part of the `navbar-text` like below.

```
 .navbar-fixed-bottom div.col-md-4:nth-child(2) .navbar-text {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
 }
```

If you can modify the code then add one new class next to `navbar-text` and apply the above styles.

```
 .new-class {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center; 
 }
```

```css
.navbar-fixed-bottom div.col-md-4:nth-child(2) .navbar-text {
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-title">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
          <p>LEFT</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="navbar-text">
          <p>PROVA MESSAGGIO</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
          <p>RIGHT</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/2t85ubfk/13/)

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
  <div class="navbar-text text-center">
    <p>PROVA MESSAGGIO</p>
  </div>
```